# @Pathvariable to classDTO

Tags: java, spring, http, request

is it possible instead of initialising all the fields of the class, just make straight class pathvariable?

I know i can use POST requests for that, but in this case i need the GET request.

**I want this**
@GetMapping("/get/{classDTO}")
    public String getMethod(@PathVariable classDTO classDTO)

**Instead of this**
@GetMapping("/get")
    public String getMethod(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String random, @PathVariable String variable, @PathVariable String hello)

Answer (score 0):

Passing multiple values (such as an object) directly in the URI is very error-prone.
However, there is a possibility to do so. Even though I would not suggest it in a real-life application. Moreover, make sure you are not passing any sensitive data.

Let's assume you have a class "Book":

```
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private int pages;

    public Book() {
    }
    // getters and setters are ommited for briefty, make sure you have them.
}
```

Your controller would look like so:

```
@RestController
public class LibraryController {

    @GetMapping("/library")
    public Book getBook(@RequestParam String book) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(book, Book.class);
    }
}
```

What is happening is that we are manually trying to map the passed String to the expected object.

Our get request then will be as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/library?book={"name": "title", "author": "someone", "pages": 400}
```

Additional resources:

While searching for the answer on the internet, I found two articles that might be of interest to you.

[Example of how to make a GET request with a map or a list](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)

[Example of how to pass an object in a GET request](https://lankydan.dev/2017/03/11/passing-data-transfer-objects-with-get-in-spring-boot)

Comment: For this case i have just wrote a custom encoder... but then i have realised that i can use @RequestParam...